# Grails domain class foreign key mapping

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I'd like to ask regarding a particular issue I have.

For example, I have a Resource table that has a product_id as foreign key of table Product.
Now my third table Consumer should have a foreign key resource_product_id which is exactly referring to product_id column of Resource table.

How should i map this scenario in grails domain class.

Thanks for your consideration. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails will handle the foreign key for you, your domains could be like this:

```
class Resource {
 Product product
}
class Product {
  ...
}
class Consumer {
 Resource resource
}
```